Importing .OBJ with Selection Sets
I'm an experienced C4D & Redshift user. I'm trying to create some (product) glTF files, and it seems like Blender is substantially more capable, than Cinema or RS.
So I'm trying to learn Blender (only installed it this morning) well enough to bridge the "divide" between Cinema & GLB.
I've exported my model from Cinema, as an .FBX (including materials and selection tags).
Blender sees the textures, and even does a fair job of creating the initial node-shaders.
However, it doesn't seem to recognize the polygon selection tags. Pretty critical issue.
I have unique materials, associated with each selection tag in C4D.
Do those not automatically import into Blender, as vertex (or whatever the proper term) selections?

I'd have thought that was down to the export file format and I don't believe it's possible with either wavefront (.obj) or fbx files. This is the Blender manual section on the FBX format and the .obj format section which you mention in your question title is here.
